# Excel on macOS: confirm warnings once and for all

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, security, vba

I'm using **Excel** 16.78 (23100802) **on** **macOS** 12.7.1 (Monterey)

I want to get rid of the following warnings:

[image]
How can I **confirm these messages once and for all**, such that they don't appear every time I open the .xlsm file?

There's no Trust Center in Excel for Mac and the steps I'd follow on Windows seem to be impossible. I could write a VBA macro? Any ideas or ready solutions?

Comment: In my opinion, your request can not be achieved, it is by design for security. If you do not want to see these warnings, it needs to keep the network or file connection being maintained. Or please remove the data connection to disassociate the data from its source via using the Data tab on Ribbon and click the Queries and Connections button.